# How to find maximum and minimum values in a particular column using python numpy?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy array(matrix in this case) which has at least 100 rows and 10 columns. Some of these columns contain numerical values and I want to find the maximum and minimum values of these columns

Here is an example of one of the columns:

```
101761
152855
99894
412379
256263
95917
122971
368797
194538
194200
132870
333158
469056
166988
113323
138107
```

Are there any ways in Python/Numpy using which I can compute maximum and minimum values of a **particular** column?

******EDIT******

Here is the actual array that I was trying to work on -

```
array([['"13316"', '26', '" Private"', '152855', '" HS-grad"', '9',
    '" Never-married"', '" Exec-managerial"', '" Own-child"',
    '" Other"', '" Female"', '0', '0', '40', '" Mexico"', '" <=50K"'],
   ['"28750"', '50', '" Self-emp-not-inc"', '99894', '" 5th-6th"', '3',
    '" Never-married"', '" Tech-support"', '" Not-in-family"',
    '" Asian-Pac-Islander"', '" Female"', '0', '0', '15',
    '" United-States"', '" <=50K"'],
   ['"30619"', '35', '" Private"', '412379', '" HS-grad"', '9',
    '" Never-married"', '" Other-service"', '" Not-in-family"',
    '" White"', '" Female"', '0', '0', '40', '" United-States"',
    '" <=50K"'],
```

some of the attributes are of numeric and some are not. I have loaded the data from the file using `np.genfromtxt` and specifying `dtype` as `None`. I have tried to use `numpy.amax` and `amin` on these particular columns but to no avail. I realised that It might be because they were loaded as strings and maybe I had to typeset them to int before doing so. I tried that as well and that seems to fail too. Any ideas on this?

Comment: As I have edited in the details, I did realize that it was probably because they were loaded as strings. I did try typesetting them to integers using `np.astype`. But even after that, amax and amin were not working.

Comment: I think you may wish to consider using the `pandas` library, it would make your life much easier. Alternatively, look up using [numpy structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).

If you post an example .csv you are using, I can show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly yet working solution, if I understand correctly your problem :

```
import numpy as np
# data : first two lines of your example
A = np.array([['"13316"', '26', '" Private"', '152855', '" HS-grad"','9',
               '" Never-married"', '" Exec-managerial"', '" Own-child"',
               '" Other"', '" Female"', '0', '0', '40', '" Mexico"', 
               '" <=50K"'],
              ['"28750"', '50', '" Self-emp-not-inc"', '99894', '"5th-6th"', '3',
'               " Never-married"', '" Tech-support"', '" Not-in-family"',
               '" Asian-Pac-Islander"', '" Female"', '0', '0', '15',
               '" United-States"', '" <=50K"']])

# extract an array containing only the columns of numbers :
numbers_columns = [0, 1, 3, 5, 11, 12, 13]
B = A[:, numbers_columns]
# remove the extra double quotes for each element of B :
C = [[b.replace('\"', '') for b in line] for line in B ]
# set as a numpy array and convert to np.int :
D = np.array(C).astype(np.int)
```

Now you have a numpy array only containing numbers. The min and max of a column i can be simply found with :

```
np.min( D[:, i] )
np.max( D[:, i] )
```

PS: I'm affraid this solution is very inelegant, but I can't think of something better. I would advise you to improve the way you read the data, to prevent this problem.

Comment: I will try this out, Thanks!